# Android: Show options menu in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-optionsmenu

I have a menu defined in an XML file such a "home_menu.xml" like this:

> ```
> <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
> <!-- Should always be in the overflow -->
> <item
>     android:id="@+id/action_settings"
>     android:showAsAction="never"
>     android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
> <item
>     android:id="@+id/action_user_preferences"
>     android:showAsAction="never"
>     android:title="@string/action_user_preferences"/>
> <item
>     android:id="@+id/action_logout" 
>     android:showAsAction="never"
>     android:title="@string/action_logout"/>
>
> </menu>
> ```

In my "Home" activity, I can access this menu by pushing the menu button in a device that has a physical button, but I don't want to use action bar so I want to add a Navigation Drawer for this purpose as Google Maps does.

It would be great if I could use the same  onOptionsItemSelected() method defined in my Home activity to handle menu actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do that.

You'll have to do it manually.

Or semi-manually. You could in onCreateOptionsMenu get all the menu items with title, icon and id and generate the view (listview for instance) for the drawer.
And use a shared method to handle the click that takes the id in parameter.
But if you want to hide/show some elements in the menu, you'll have to update your listview manually since onCreateOptionsMenu won't be called. And if you have multiple fragment with menus you'll also have to do something.

So I would recommend to use the drawer even when there is a hardware menu key.

Comment: Manually means to duplicate options menu in a List?